# iptables: built-in INPUT chain in nat table?

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a Gentoo Linux system running linux 2.6.38-rc8.  I also have a machine running Ubuntu with linux 2.6.35-27.  I also have a virtual machine running Debian Unstable with linux 2.6.37-2.

On the Gentoo and Debian systems I have an INPUT chain built into my nat table in addition to PREROUTING, OUTPUT, and POSTROUTING.
On Ubuntu, I only have PREROUTING, OUTPUT, and POSTROUTING.

I am able to use this INPUT chain to use SNAT to modify the source of a packet that is destined to the local machine (imagine simulating an incoming spoofed IP to a local application or just to test a virtual host configuration).  This is possible with 2 firewall rules on Gentoo and Debian but seemingly not so on Ubuntu.  I looked around for documentation on changes to the SNAT target and the INPUT chain of the nat table and I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know if this is a configuration issue or is it something that was just added in more recent versions of linux?

Comment: Honestly, this is the first time I've ever heard of `-t nat -A INPUT`. Can't even find the most up-to-date man page for iptables referring to nat/INPUT.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was added some time after 2.6.35, see [commit c68cd6cc21eb329c47ff020ff7412bf58176984e](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=c68cd6cc21eb329c47ff020ff7412bf58176984e)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the link. Geez, the netfilter guys should really recruit someone to keep their man pages up-to-date.

Comment: [According to Github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c68cd6cc21eb329c47ff020ff7412bf58176984e), this indeed went into v2.6.36

Comment: netfilter has no man page